# TYPO3 Backend showing whole Variable Name

Tags: php, apache, typo3

So after I updated my TYPO3 from 8.7.6 to 8.7.24, the backend seems broken.

I can log in normally and also the install tool works fine.

But the whole site looks a bit odd.
Here's how it looks:

[image]

I don't know if I can edit this in the settings or anywhere else but I don't think this is normal. On the web I searched with `typo3 backend broken variables`.

Here is my System:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
- TYPO3 CMS 8.7.24
- PHP 7.2.15
- MYSQL 5.5.60

Extensions in my ext folder:

- TemplavoilaPlus 7.3.0
- Static Info Tables

I have tried deleting all the cache, restarting the webserver and restarting the whole server. And nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No PHP needed. Just go into the *Admin Tools/Settings* module, click "Configure options" in the "Configure Installation-Wide Options" box, search for "debug," and uncheck [BE][languageDebug]. Scroll to the bottom and click "Write configuration" which will save the changes to your LocalConfiguration.php file. Then, click your browser's reload button so the interface is reloaded.

Currently [BE][languageDebug] has been set to "true" in your installation, so the language labels are being shown. This setting can be useful if you are translating the backend, or just want to change some wording. It gives you the identifier and the file to override.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you enabled the language debug mode. You can disable it by adding `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['languageDebug'] = false;` in your `AdditionalConfiguration.php`.